# safaridriver can't be enabled

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, safaridriver

I'm trying to use the safaridriver but every time I try to enable it I get a segmentation fault.
I already tried to restart my laptop but the problems stays.

```
admin@Bens-Air ~ % safaridriver --enable
Password:
zsh: segmentation fault  safaridriver --enable
```

Thankful for any help :)

Comment: Which version are you using? Have you tried running it with elevated privileges -> 'sudo -u <your user> safaridriver --enable'  ?

Comment: @Prome Yes I tried running it with ```sudo -u <your user> safaridriver --enable``` and with ```sudo safaridriver --enable```but it still gives me the segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why, but it works now.

I gave the user im trying to work on with safaridriver the rights to change files of the computer.
Also I seem to have used safaridriver (after giving more rights to the user) in python(I have no clue how I actually used it - but it works).
So when I decided to try it again it now worked without the error described in the question.